# Spring Boot JPA Select by criteria getting NullPointerException

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am new at Spring Boot Technology.I am using JPA Repository with MySQL DB.I am getting an error as NullPointer Exception.

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Integer> {   


    @Query(value="SELECT * FROM User u WHERE u.isUserLoggedIn = 1", nativeQuery = true)
    List<User> findUserLastLoggedIn();

}
```

My Table

```
   CREATE TABLE `user` (  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `_id` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(300) NOT NULL,
  `salt` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT (1),
  `insert_date` datetime DEFAULT (now()),
  `last_login_time` datetime DEFAULT (now()),
  `name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `surname` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `alias_name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `access_token` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `refresh_token` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_user_logged_in` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
   ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=12 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 
     COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

**User Entity as like this:**

```
@Entity
public class User {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)

private int id;

private String _id;
private String email;
private String password;
private String salt;
private int status;
private Date insertDate;
private Date lastLoginTime;
private String name;
private String surname;
private String aliasName;
private String accessToken;
private String refreshToken;
private int isUserLoggedIn;

//getter and setter ...
```

}

**My StackTrace :**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at me.sikke.UserController.findUserLastLoggedIn(UserController.java:111) ~[classes/:na]
at me.sikke.WalletController.createWallet(WalletController.java:25) ~[classes/:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:209) ~[spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136) ~[spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:877) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:783) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:974) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:866) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:851) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:496) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1468) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_191]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_191]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_191]
```

[my repository is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N2GGv.png) I couldn't understand the problem.You can see the my interface here

**My UserController class**

```
@RestController
public class UserController {

@Autowired
UserRepository sikkeRespository;

@RequestMapping(value = "/getAccessToken", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<String> getAccessToken(@RequestBody LoginUser loginUser) {
    List<User> userList = sikkeRespository.findUserLastLoggedIn();
    if (userList != null && userList.size() > 0) {
        return new ResponseEntity<String>("There are currently active users. 
  Please exit and try again.", HttpStatus.OK);
    }
    if (SikkeHelper.checkLoginUser(loginUser)) {
        String username = loginUser.getEmail();
        String password = loginUser.getPassword();
        List<NameValuePair> urlParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("grant_type", "password"));
        urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
        urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
        try {
            String jsonString = ConnectionInfo.call(SikkeConstant.accessTokenUrl, urlParameters);
            User user = new User();
            if (jsonString != null) {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonString);
                String status = jsonObj.getString("status");
                if (SikkeConstant.STATUS_SUCCESS.equals(status)) {
                    System.out.println("Login Succeed : " + 
    jsonObj.getString("email"));
                    user.setPassword(password);
                    SikkeHelper.fillUserFromJson(jsonObj, user);
                    User userExisting = 
sikkeRespository.findByEmail(username);
                    userExisting.setIsUserLoggedIn(1);
                    if (userExisting != null) {
                        userExisting.setAccessToken(user.getAccessToken());

 userExisting.setRefreshToken(user.getRefreshToken());
                        sikkeRespository.save(userExisting);
                    } else {
                        sikkeRespository.save(user);
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new SikkeException(e.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new SikkeException(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<String>("Session successfully opened.", 
   HttpStatus.OK);
    }

@RequestMapping(value = "/registerUser", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<String> registerUser(@RequestBody LoginUser loginUser) 
{
    if (SikkeHelper.checkLoginUser(loginUser)) {
        String username = loginUser.getEmail();
        String password = loginUser.getPassword();
        List<NameValuePair> urlParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", username));
        urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
        urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password_confirm", 
  password));
        try {
            String jsonString = 
  ConnectionInfo.call(SikkeConstant.registerUserUrl, urlParameters);
            User user = new User();
            if (jsonString != null) {
                JSONObject jsonObj;

                jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonString);
                String status = jsonObj.getString("status");
                if (SikkeConstant.STATUS_SUCCESS.equals(status)) {
                    JSONObject userJson = jsonObj.getJSONObject("user");
                    user.setPassword(password);
                    SikkeHelper.fillUserFromJson(userJson, user);
                    sikkeRespository.save(user);
                } else if (SikkeConstant.STATUS_ERROR.equals(status)) {
                    System.out.println(jsonObj.getString("message"));
                }
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            throw new SikkeException(e.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new SikkeException(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<String>("User created.", HttpStatus.OK);
   }

@RequestMapping(value = "/logOut", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<String> logOut() {
    int effectedRow = sikkeRespository.logoutAllUser();
    return new ResponseEntity<String>("Logout done successfully.", 
HttpStatus.OK);
}

public List<User> findUserLastLoggedIn() {
    List<User> userList = sikkeRespository.findUserLastLoggedIn();
    return userList;
  }
 }


List<User> userList = userController.findUserLastLoggedIn();
```

the below line in Wallet Controller calls the method findUserLastLoggedIn in UserController

**My WalletController**

```
@RestController
 public class WalletController {

@Autowired
WalletRepository walletRepository;
@Autowired
UserController userController;

@RequestMapping(value = "/createWallet")
public ResponseEntity<String> createWallet() {
    Wallet wallet = new Wallet();
    userController = new UserController();
    List<User> userList = userController.findUserLastLoggedIn();
    if (userList == null) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>("Active user not found. You must login 
 to the system.", HttpStatus.OK);
    }
    if (userList.size() == 1) {
        User user = null;//userList.get(0);
        wallet.setwOwnerId(Integer.parseInt(user.get_id()));
        WalletKey walletKey = WalletKey.getWalletKeys();
        wallet.setwPubKey(walletKey.getPublicKey());
        wallet.setwZeugma(walletKey.getPrivateKey());
        wallet.setwNumber(walletKey.getWalletNumber());
        walletRepository.save(wallet);
        return new ResponseEntity<>("Wallet created.", HttpStatus.OK);
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<String>("Wallet creation failed", 
 HttpStatus.OK);
}
}
```

@Spara

Updated WalletController after deleting userController = new UserController line

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qpF91.png)

Where is the problem on my code, could you pleaase help me?

Comment: Can you show us your "User" entity class?

Comment: Try changing the data type all the "int" fields to its wrapper class "Integer" in your User class.

Comment: did you tried my answer bro?

Comment: unfortunately both of them did not work.Bro.I couldn't understand the problem.

Comment: would you please add your error stack trace ?

Comment: @Baltazar Please try replacing int with Integer in your entity class and let me know if it worked. Use of primitives should be avoided in entity class as they may result in nullPointerException in case of nulls.

Comment: Are you sure that you use @Autowired when defining UserController?

Comment: @Autowired
private UserController userController;

Comment: and also @Autowired
private UserRepository userRepository;

Comment: Or defining them in constructor

Comment: UserRepository userRepository in UserController defined  as @Autowired

Comment: @AdityaNarayanDixit I converted primitive int to Integer object but doesn't work unfourtunalely

Comment: Aha I find your problem! please delete this line : userController = new UserController(); in your walletController and just let it autowired from spring; when you customly new controller the life cycle of object is not in spring hand and makes you problems

Comment: If I delete the line you mentioned, how should I change the code.I couldn't understand your solution

Comment: Autowired is enough. you have already autowired it and you should avoid to make it new again.

Comment: for more information please visit https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19896870/why-is-my-spring-autowired-field-null

Comment: @Spara I posted updated WalletController class, but not change

Comment: Ok, It's not good Idea to Autowire Controllers in each other. This time please Autowire your userRepository into WalletController and make call directly; I will update my answer and check if its working or not.

Comment: I updated my answer and corrected WalletController by injecting userRepository in it. Please check if it's working or not then tell me what's happen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `nativeQuery = true` it will run your query natively so you should write query in this way:

```
@Query(value="SELECT * FROM User u WHERE u.is_user_logged_in = 1", nativeQuery = true)
List<User> findUserLastLoggedIn();
```

The other way is to do not use `nativeQuery`:

```
@Query(value="SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.isUserLoggedIn = 1")
List<User> findUserLastLoggedIn();
```

Please delete this line in your WalletController:

```
userController = new UserController();
```

This makes you `NullPointerException` on `@Autowired` fields

For more information please visit [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19896870/why-is-my-spring-autowired-field-null)

```
@RestController
 public class WalletController {

@Autowired
WalletRepository walletRepository;
@Autowired
UserRepository userRepository;

@RequestMapping(value = "/createWallet")
public ResponseEntity<String> createWallet() {
    Wallet wallet = new Wallet();
    List<User> userList = userRepository.findUserLastLoggedIn();
    if (userList == null) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>("Active user not found. You must login 
 to the system.", HttpStatus.OK);
    }
    if (userList.size() == 1) {
        User user = null;//userList.get(0);
        wallet.setwOwnerId(Integer.parseInt(user.get_id()));
        WalletKey walletKey = WalletKey.getWalletKeys();
        wallet.setwPubKey(walletKey.getPublicKey());
        wallet.setwZeugma(walletKey.getPrivateKey());
        wallet.setwNumber(walletKey.getWalletNumber());
        walletRepository.save(wallet);
        return new ResponseEntity<>("Wallet created.", HttpStatus.OK);
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<String>("Wallet creation failed", 
 HttpStatus.OK);
}
}
```

Comment: my bro.You are the KING. I arranged it like you said.This is working perfectly .Thank you very much. You saved me from a big trouble.

Comment: I'm happy that I could solve your problem :) @Baltazar

Comment: you're as big as the problem you solve. It's nice to encounter this problem when learning Spring boot :))

Comment: I have an another problem.Could you please help me?is it possible to look and comment? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53647122/how-to-run-spring-boot-web-service-on-command-line-cmd-without-using-curl-like

Answer (score 1):

Instead of native query you can use spring data jpa itself like below.

```
public List<User> findByIsUserLoggedIn(Integer isUserLoggedIn);
```

If boolean field then try with below.

```
public Iterable<Entity> findByIsUserLoggedInTrue();
```

The [JPA repository section](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/current/reference/html#jpa.query-methods.named-queries) query creation has the following methods.

```
True    findByActiveTrue()  … where x.active = true
False   findByActiveFalse() … where x.active = false
```

So you can use

```
@Query
public Iterable<Entity> findByEnabledTrue();
```

Comment: (Integer 1) is getting error as identifer expected ;

Comment: it may be any variable and you have to set it before accessing like 0 or 1. updated the answer by putting variable name...to call this method you can use like userRepository.findByIsUserLoggedIn(1);